# how to convert the below stream to pdf file in react or javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</Alternate/DeviceRGB/N 3/Length 2595/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
xwTT×Ï½wz¡Í0)Cï½
 ½7©ÒDa`(34±!¢EDA""±"`Á  Ä`QQy3²Vtåå½ßg}k½÷=gï}Öº¼ý¹¼tX
```

I called an ajax call , I need to convert these streams to pdf files.

component:

```
export default class CharityCheckReport extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await AdminGrantTaskService.getCharityCheckStream();
    const data = await response.blob();
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, "filename");
  }
}
```

service:

```
import { ajax } from "rxjs/ajax";

const headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/blob"
};

export class AdminGrantTaskService {
  static async getCharityCheckStream(action) {
    const req = await fetch("/v2/", headers);
    return req;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const file = new Blob(
    [data], 
    {type: 'application/pdf'});
//Build a URL from the file
const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
//Open the URL on new Window
window.open(fileURL);
```

Comment: Thank's Denis, Tried opening a blank pdf file. data is getting but not writing in to the pdf file

Comment: axios.get("/v2/").then(res => {
      const file = new Blob([res.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
      
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
     
      window.open(fileURL);
    });